# Junit/Hamcrest - Does any of the specified text appear on the page?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I am trying to use Junit and Selenium WebDriver to find misspelled words, from a word bank, on a website. I am also using Hamcrest which is now included in Junit.

```
@Test
public void filter() throws Exception {

    driver.get("http://www.ExampleWebsite.org/selenium-filter-test/");

    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*"));
    String content = body.getText();

    assertThat(content, anyOf (
            equalTo("foo"),
            equalTo("Charoit"),
            equalTo("Micha")));
}
```

The problem is that I am having issues comparing what is on the page to the three words in the test. I think the specified string "content" is comparing all of the text on the page as one whole string. I need it to find if any of those words are contained in "content."

Am I approaching this the correct way? Or would you recommend something better?

Thank You.

Micah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the String.contains() method.  For example:

```
boolean success 
    = content.contains("foo") 
    || content.contains("Charoit") 
    || content.contains("Micha");
Assert.assertEquals
    ("content contains 'foo', 'Charoit', or 'Micha'", true, success);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. I am looking into this more to better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the guava Splitter class. You can find some examples [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter).

The string is split, use a for to check for each of the values you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I am reading up on all these things now. This helps so much!